# Show $\det(A+B+C)\geq \det(A+C)+\det(B+C)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, proof-writing, determinant

I came across this theorem for positive semi-definite matrices. Does anyone know a proof of this?

Comment: Well, it seems false (or not applicable) for $1\times 1$ matrices.

Comment: False in general: take $C:=I_n$, $A,B:=\text{diag}(1,0,\dots,0)$.